# How to get which event is fired when a jquery validation executes?

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using jquery validation and I have added a method using '.addMethod' for a field validation. I want to get the event type inside that custom function. I have used "event.type" for this purpose and its working fine in chrome. Its not working in Mozilla Firefox.

My code example is below

```
$.validator.addMethod("my method name", function(value, element, params) {
console.log(event.type);//it shows "submit" in chrome
},'my message');
```

How can I access the event type inside that custom method?
OR
How can I pass event object into the custom method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The event object is only available in invalidHandler and submitHandler but those are triggered after validation. I think you have to solve this without the validator plugin.